# register serviceprovider at runtime instead of app.php

Tags: laravel

Is it possible to register serviceprovider at runtime instead of having it preregistered in app.php providers list? If yes how would it be done? Could I register it from some other service provider that is aready in app.php and running?

Comment: Please give an example of a scenario where it might be necessary to boot a service provider before the application has booted.

Comment: I am making a CMS where I would like to have extensions that can easily be installed by endusers, I can't ask end user to modify app.php so I would like to load all activated extensions serviceprovider at runtime, is this possible is what I would like to know and if possible could you provide me with idea how and where to load them?

Answer (score 0):

its possible to register a service provider at any time by calling the register method on the ioc container...

Using the facade:

App::register($yourProvider);
Using the helper:

app()->register($yourProvider);